# Transpose a table in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to transpose below table

| Name | Occupation |
| --- | --- |
| Samantha | Doctor |
| Julia | Actor |
| Maria | Actor |
| Ashley | Professor |
| Meera | Singer |
| Ketty | Professor |
| Kristen | Actor |
| Jenny | Doctor |
| Jane | Cell 2 |
| Priya | Singer |

using:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN occupation= 'Doctor' THEN Name ELSE NULL END AS Doctor,     
       CASE WHEN occupation= 'Professor' THEN Name ELSE NULL END AS Professor,     
       CASE WHEN occupation= 'Actor' THEN Name ELSE NULL END AS Actor,     
       CASE WHEN occupation= 'Singer' THEN Name ELSE NULL END AS Singer  
FROM occupations;
```

My result set looks like

```
Doctor  Professor   Actor       Singer
Samantha NULL       NULL        NULL
NULL     NULL       Julia       NULL
NULL     NULL       Maria       NULL
NULL     NULL       NULL        Meera
NULL     Ashley     NULL        NULL
NULL     Ketty      NULL        NULL
NULL    Kristen     NULL        NULL
NULL     NULL       Jane        NULL
Jenny    NULL       NULL        NULL
NULL     NULL       NULL        Priya
```

But I need my result set to be:

```
Doctor    Professor Actor       Singer
Jenny     Ashley    Jane        Meera
Samantha  Ketty     Julia       Priya
NULL      Kristen   Maria       NULL
```

Comment: Is the list of Occupations static? What is MySQL version?

Comment: @akina Yes this is static and using 8

Comment: Enumerate in CTE (ROW_NUMBER) over an occupation then use conditional aggregation by this number.

Comment: Anything other than Doctor    Professor Actor       Singer to be ignored eg jane/cell2?

Comment: @P.Salmon That's just a typo...yeah if Jane/Cell2 is NULL, can show that under Cell2 column.

Comment: @Akina Can you please elaborate? I have tried with row number but could not get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH
cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY occupation ORDER BY name) rn
    FROM occupations
)
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN occupation='Doctor'    THEN Name END) AS Doctor,     
       MAX(CASE WHEN occupation='Professor' THEN Name END) AS Professor,     
       MAX(CASE WHEN occupation='Actor'     THEN Name END) AS Actor,     
       MAX(CASE WHEN occupation='Singer'    THEN Name END) AS Singer  
FROM cte
GROUP BY rn
```